# How to create a nested forloop on a RDD (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD that has the following structure:
`((ByteArray, Idx), ((srcIdx,srcAdress), (destIdx,destAddress)))`

This the representation of an edge (a transaction) of the bitcoin blockchain. `(ByteArray, Idx)` can be seen as an identifier, there rest is an edge. My ultimate goal is to aggregate nodes in a graph representation of the blockchain. The first modification to the structure I need to do for this, is putting sources that are in the same bitcoin transaction together in one edge (and eventually in one node). In this way I would "cluster" public keys that belong to the same user. 
The result of this modification would have the following structure:
`((ByteArray, Idx), (List((srcIdx, srcAddress)), (destIdx, destAddress)))`
Or in any other form has the same functionality (for example if this is not possible or logical within Scala).

My current thought process is as follows. In Java I would do a nested for loop over the items in the RDD, each loop creating a list for those items that have the same key (`(ByteArray, Idx)`). After this deleting any duplicates.
However, since I'm dealing with RDDs and Scala, this is not possible. Next I tried to do a `.collect()` and then a seperate `.map()` function on my RDD, using the collection to be looped over within my map function. However, Spark did not like this, since apparently collections cannot be serialized. 
Next I tried to create a "nested" map function as following:

```
val aggregatedTransactions = joinedTransactions.map( f => {
  var list = List[Any](f._2._1)

  val filtered = joinedTransactions.filter(t => f._1 == t._1)

  for(i <- filtered){
    list ::= i._2._1
  }

  (f._1, list, f._2._2)
})
```

This is not allowed, since the the filter (or map) function is not available in a .map(). What are the alternatives?

I'm quite new to Scala so any background information that is usefull is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think, given the nature of your problem, it would be useful to provide input +output examples to avoid misunderstanding

Answer (score 5):

> My ultimate goal is to aggregate nodes in a graph representation of the blockchain. The first modification to the structure I need to do for this, is putting sources that are in the same bitcoin transaction together in one edge (and eventually in one node).

So essentially you want to `groupByKey`:

```
joinedTransactions.groupByKey().map {
   // process data to get desired shape
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Nested RDDs are not possible however collections within an RDD is
>   possible .

Nested for loop you can use [cartesian](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)

> def cartesian[U](other: RDD[U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[(T,
>   U)]  Permalink Return the Cartesian product of this RDD and another
>   one, that is, the RDD of all pairs of elements (a, b) where a is in
>   this and b is in other.

```
val nestedForRDD = rdd1.cartesian(rdd2)

nestedForRDD.map((rdd1TypeVal, rdd2TypeVal) => {
  //Do your inner-nested evaluation code here
})
```

Using Spark SQL you can also achieve it.

http://bigdatums.net/2016/02/12/how-to-extract-nested-json-data-in-spark/